# Early withdrawal from retirement appears to have been penalized at 35% (on top of regular income taxes), rather than 25%?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement

I had to withdraw from my Simple IRA retirement fund last year for emergency reasons. When I withdrew, the IRA company withheld 10% for federal taxes. When I did my taxes at the end of the year though, I was charged 25% in taxes. The form I received for the withdraw said that the taxable portion is XXX (where XXX is the total amount withdraw), not YYY (where YYY is the amount withdrawn after 10% withheld), and the form also said (box 4) the amount that was withheld and "taxable amount not determined"

So, my total penalty charged for the early withdrawal was 35% (along with it being counted as income and such, of course). Is there any case where this could happen, or was my taxes done wrongly?

Comment: According to JoeTaxpayer's answer, it should have only been penalized 25%. More than likely you received credit for the 10% that was withheld on a Form 1099-R. If you really were penalized 35%, check with whoever did your taxes or tax software.

Answer (score 5):

From [SIMPLE IRA Plan FAQs - Distributions](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/SIMPLE-IRA-Plan-FAQs-Distributions) -

"....a distribution within this 2-year period, then the rate of additional tax under this special rule is increased from 10 percent to 25 percent."

This means you have tax on the full amount, plus a penalty of 25% if the account is less than 2 years old.

Comment: Where is the quote from?